# Use shim with UEFI Fedora 20

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, efi

How do I use shim with Fedora 20? I have the KDE version, if you need to know that. Running kernel 3.11, with secure boot enabled. At boot, this message is shown:

```
    EFI: Problem loading in-kernel x.509 certificate (-129)
```

How do I get rid of this message using shim? I already have shim.efi in my /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/ directory.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a standard Fedora kernel, that message should *not* appear, since the standard kernel is signed. If you're using a locally-compiled kernel, you should be able to sign it with your own key and enroll that key as a Machine Owner Key (MOK) so that Shim will give it the thumbs-up. For more on this topic, see [my page on Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) or various other pages that describe the same topic but that I don't happen to have bookmarked.

If you're booting a standard kernel and seeing that message, then that suggests a bug somewhere along the line. The most reliable way to bypass it is to disable Secure Boot in your firmware. The details of how to do this depend greatly on your EFI implementation, so I can't be very specific about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I am not very tech-savvy, and I am just starting to learn Linux. I have seen your page on SB before, but I do not know how to follow the instructions. I have shim.efi already, I just don't know how to add it to GRUB2 configuration.

Comment: PS: I am using the standard F20 3.11 kernel.

Comment: I know how to disable SB, but don't want to for this reason: After I do, it gives me a delay during boot saying `Booting in insecure mode` Then, it hangs for 5 seconds. :(

Comment: Any ideas??? Sorry for being a noob :D

Comment: Nobody??? I'm still clueless here.

Comment: You say it "hangs for 5 seconds." That implies it then proceeds normally. If so, then the problem is solved, although a 5-second delay *might* constitute another problem. Also, concerning your original post, you haven't really identified a problem -- just a message that you don't want to see. Are you experiencing any actual functional problems, aside from that message?

Comment: No, not really, although the wireless does not work... `modprobe wl` returns `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available` which probably has something to do with SB.

Comment: I recommend you start a new question about your WiFi problem. It may well be related to Secure Boot, but the way your question is phrased now does not make it clear what the *real* problem is. It's been long enough that re-phrasing your current question will not attract new eyeballs to it.

Comment: Ok, *sigh*. Will start new post